# Arraylist of Arrays, How to make last array size somehow different from other arrays in the list

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

**Explanation of what i am trying to acheive:**

I am given a  file and i have to read data from the file and create blocks of sizes 1 kb. For example : If the file size is 5.8 kb then i will have 5 blocks of 1 kb each and 1 last block of 0.8 kb. After having these in the block i have to do SHA 256 encoding from the last block and append it to the second last block, after that i have to apply the encoding to the second last block and append it to the third last and so on.

**Problem**

If i am given multiple of 1024 byte file size then my code works well. But if my last block size is not 1024 then the code doesnot work as intended.

The way i am doing this now is :

```
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
int sizeOfBlock = 1024;
int sizeOfHash = 256;

MessageDigest md;
md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");

byte[] block = new byte[sizeOfBlock];

List <byte []> blockList = new ArrayList <byte []>();

int tmp = 0;
while ((tmp = bis.read(block)) > 0) {
    System.out.println(tmp);
    blockList.add(block);           
}       

for (int j = blockList.size()-1; j > 0;){
    System.out.println(blockList.get(j).length); // for the first iteration it shouldnt be 1024 if the file size is not a multiple of 1024
    md.update(blockList.get(j--));
    byte[] hash = md.digest();
    byte[] appendBlock = new byte[blockList.get(j).length + hash.length];

    System.arraycopy(blockList.get(j), 0, appendBlock, 0, blockList.get(j).length);
    System.arraycopy(md.digest(), 0, appendBlock, blockList.get(j).length, hash.length);
    blockList.set(j, appendBlock);      
}

System.out.println(blockList.get(0).length);
md.update(blockList.get(0));
byte[] hash = md.digest();

String result = bytesToHex(hash); // converting function from byte to hex
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: why does not it work? what is the specific problem you are facing?

Comment: You are overwriting everything you previously read in your while loop by reusing the same array. You have a list of many references to the same array containing only the last 1024 bytes you read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you are adding the same 1024 byte array to the array list again and again.
So of course all of the arrays will be 1024 bytes. They are the same array.
In addition, you are overwriting the `block` array every time you call read, so it will contain the last block you read from the file.
You should store a copy of the array in the array list.

You should do something like :

```
while ((tmp = bis.read(block)) > 0) {
    byte[] currentBlock = new byte[tmp];
    System.arraycopy (block, 0, currentBlock, 0, tmp);
    System.out.println(tmp);
    blockList.add(currentBlock);           
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It appears the error originates from here:

```
int tmp = 0;
while ((tmp = bis.read(block)) > 0) {
    System.out.println(tmp);
    blockList.add(block);           
}
```

Arrays are reference types in java, so when you pass an array you pass it by reference just like any Object. This means that when you call `bis.read(block)` you are placing the bytes into the array you've already allocated. That is, you read a block into, `block`, then add it to `blocksList` then when you read another block into the same variable, it replaces the contents of that array, so you've really added 5 copies of the array.

Here's your list structure

- Element 0 -> `block`
- Element 1 -> `block`
- Element 2 -> `block`

where all these `block`s are the same array.

You really want

- Element 0 -> `block1`
- Element 1 -> `block2`
- Element 2 -> `block3`

where these are all different arrays. You can fix this by allocating a new array each time you read a block.

Now, this is causing a problem because you expect the array length to be shorter than 1024 bytes. However, because it's the same array, the array length equals 1024 bytes, which triggers your problems.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to say. But i cannt think of how and what changes should i make to the code :/

Comment: @LivingThing check the suggestion in my answer.